# Is this phrasing right grammatically for use in resume? "International Finalist, International Math Olympiads"

Tags: punctuation

Is this phrasing right grammatically for use in Resume? "International Finalist, International Math Olympiads"
Is the comma use here right?

Comment: Why repeat 'International'? You could write "Finalist in 2019 International Math Olympiads" or "Finalist, 2019 International Math Olympiads". For the purpose of a resume, it doesn't matter if there were two classes of finalist – it bloats the wording.

Comment: If _International Finalist_ is a recognized degree/rank/award/designation in the International Math Olympiads organization, it should be used. If it's not officially designated, but merely echoes the international character of the organization, then it should not be used. If it is to be used, phrase it with a verb: _reached "International Finalist" level, International Math Olympiad_. Of course this means you should phrase other achievements with verbs, which is better form anyway. Achievements are events, and need verbs.